# How to save the HTML into a variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm building an app using Angular 2 and at a given point I want to send a mail. The body of this mail will contain exactly a part of the code being rendered in the template (I'm creating a table from a list of elements).

I'm looking for a way to get the existing html being displayed and save it into a variable so I can add it to my mail body.

There are plenty of options to do the opposite (print html from a variable) but not the way I need. Any idea?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem? `document.body.outerHTML` doesn't work or `constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef){} ... this.elementRef.nativeElement.outerHTML`?

Comment: Sounds good. How do you refer to a specific element by id or class with this?

Comment: You can use `this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(...)` and use the selector you need/want/....

Comment: It looks like elementRef is not the best idea... https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html

Comment: I guess using the browser is the greater security risk ;-) The risk is if you add stuff from insecure sources to the DOM using `ElementRef`, because this way Angulars sanitizer is eluded. The security risk is similar to using `document.body` directly.

Comment: ElementRef did the job. Thanks for that! If you post the answer I'll up vote it (so other people can solve this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the HTML from a child element of a component you can use:

```
constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {}

createMail() {
  return this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('...').innerHTML;
}
```